AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cuda'
I'm encountering an AttributeError when trying to run a PPO trainer on an OR-GYM environment for inventory management using Ray RLlib and PyTorch in a CPU-only setup. Despite explicitly setting num_gpus=0 in the configuration, the error persists.
Environment:
Python 3.9
Ray 2.1.0
PyTorch (CPU version confirmed)
OR-GYM
Tensorflow 2.3.0
gym 0.13.1
Library imports
import or_gym
from or_gym.utils import create_env
import ray
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPOTrainer

from ray import tune
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

Configuration:
rl_config = {
    'env': env_name,
    'num_workers': 8,
    'num_gpus': 0,
    'env_config': env_config,
    'model': {
        'vf_share_layers': False,
        'fcnet_activation': 'relu',
        'fcnet_hiddens': [256, 256]
    },
    'framework': 'torch',
    'lr': 1e-5,
    'clip_param': 0.2
}


Code for Trainer Initialization:
ray.shutdown()
register_env(env_name, env_config)
ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True)

agent = agents.ppo.PPOTrainer(env=env_name, config=rl_config)
results = []
for i in range(1200):
    res = agent.train()
    results.append(res)
    if (i+1) % 5 == 0:
        print('\nIter: {}\tReward: {:.2f}'.format(i+1, res['episode_reward_mean']), end='')
        print('\n')
ray.shutdown()


Error Trace:
The error occurs when initializing the PPOTrainer:
2024-04-25 18:30:58,063 INFO worker.py:1528 -- Started a local Ray instance.
(RolloutWorker pid=24100) 2024-04-25 18:31:06,911   WARNING env.py:147 -- Your env doesn't have a .spec.max_episode_steps attribute. This is fine if you have set 'horizon' in your config dictionary, or `soft_horizon`. However, if you haven't, 'horizon' will default to infinity, and your environment will not be reset.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 11
      7 # Initialize Ray and Build Agent
      8 # Initialize Ray and Build Agent
      9 ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True)
---> 11 agent = agents.ppo.PPOTrainer(env=env_name,
     12     config=rl_config)
     13 results = []
     14 for i in range(1200):

File ~\vlsecondrl\lib\site-packages\ray\rllib\algorithms\algorithm.py:414, in Algorithm.__init__(self, config, env, logger_creator, **kwargs)
    402 # Initialize common evaluation_metrics to nan, before they become
    403 # available. We want to make sure the metrics are always present
    404 # (although their values may be nan), so that Tune does not complain
    405 # when we use these as stopping criteria.
    406 self.evaluation_metrics = {
    407     "evaluation": {
    408         "episode_reward_max": np.nan,
   (...)
    411     }
    412 }
--> 414 super().__init__(config=config, logger_creator=logger_creator, **kwargs)
    416 # Check, whether `training_iteration` is still a tune.Trainable property
    417 # and has not been overridden by the user in the attempt to implement the
    418 # algos logic (this should be done now inside `training_step`).
    419 try:

File ~\vlsecondrl\lib\site-packages\ray\tune\trainable\trainable.py:161, in Trainable.__init__(self, config, logger_creator, remote_checkpoint_dir, custom_syncer, sync_timeout)
    159 start_time = time.time()
    160 self._local_ip = ray.util.get_node_ip_address()
--> 161 self.setup(copy.deepcopy(self.config))
    162 setup_time = time.time() - start_time
    163 if setup_time > SETUP_TIME_THRESHOLD:

File ~\vlsecondrl\lib\site-packages\ray\rllib\algorithms\algorithm.py:524, in Algorithm.setup(self, config)
    517 if _init is False:
    518     # - Create rollout workers here automatically.
    519     # - Run the execution plan to create the local iterator to `next()`
    520     #   in each training iteration.
    521     # This matches the behavior of using `build_trainer()`, which
    522     # has been deprecated.
    523     try:
--> 524         self.workers = WorkerSet(
    525             env_creator=self.env_creator,
    526             validate_env=self.validate_env,
    527             policy_class=self.get_default_policy_class(self.config),
    528             trainer_config=self.config,
    529             num_workers=self.config["num_workers"],
    530             local_worker=True,
    531             logdir=self.logdir,
    532         )
    533     # WorkerSet creation possibly fails, if some (remote) workers cannot
    534     # be initialized properly (due to some errors in the RolloutWorker's
    535     # constructor).
    536     except RayActorError as e:
    537         # In case of an actor (remote worker) init failure, the remote worker
    538         # may still exist and will be accessible, however, e.g. calling
    539         # its `sample.remote()` would result in strange "property not found"
    540         # errors.

File ~\vlsecondrl\lib\site-packages\ray\rllib\evaluation\worker_set.py:185, in WorkerSet.__init__(self, env_creator, validate_env, policy_class, trainer_config, num_workers, local_worker, logdir, _setup)
    182     spaces = None
    184 if local_worker:
--> 185     self._local_worker = self._make_worker(
    186         cls=RolloutWorker,
    187         env_creator=env_creator,
    188         validate_env=validate_env,
    189         policy_cls=self._policy_class,
    190         # Initially, policy_specs will be inferred from config dict.
    191         policy_specs=None,
    192         worker_index=0,
    193         num_workers=num_workers,
    194         config=self._local_config,
    195         spaces=spaces,
    196     )

File ~\vlsecondrl\lib\site-packages\ray\rllib\evaluation\worker_set.py:892, in WorkerSet._make_worker(self, cls, env_creator, validate_env, policy_cls, policy_specs, worker_index, num_workers, recreated_worker, config, spaces)
    889 else:
    890     extra_python_environs = config.get("extra_python_environs_for_worker", None)
--> 892 worker = cls(
    893     env_creator=env_creator,
    894     validate_env=validate_env,
    895     policy_spec=policy_specs,
    896     policy_mapping_fn=config["multiagent"]["policy_mapping_fn"],
    897     policies_to_train=config["multiagent"]["policies_to_train"],
    898     tf_session_creator=(session_creator if config["tf_session_args"] else None),
    899     rollout_fragment_length=config["rollout_fragment_length"],
    900     count_steps_by=config["multiagent"]["count_steps_by"],
    901     batch_mode=config["batch_mode"],
    902     episode_horizon=config["horizon"],
    903     preprocessor_pref=config["preprocessor_pref"],
    904     sample_async=config["sample_async"],
    905     compress_observations=config["compress_observations"],
    906     num_envs=config["num_envs_per_worker"],
    907     observation_fn=config["multiagent"]["observation_fn"],
    908     clip_rewards=config["clip_rewards"],
    909     normalize_actions=config["normalize_actions"],
    910     clip_actions=config["clip_actions"],
    911     env_config=config["env_config"],
    912     policy_config=config,
    913     worker_index=worker_index,
    914     num_workers=num_workers,
    915     recreated_worker=recreated_worker,
    916     log_dir=self._logdir,
    917     log_level=config["log_level"],
    918     callbacks=config["callbacks"],
    919     input_creator=input_creator,
    920     output_creator=output_creator,
    921     remote_worker_envs=config["remote_worker_envs"],
    922     remote_env_batch_wait_ms=config["remote_env_batch_wait_ms"],
    923     soft_horizon=config["soft_horizon"],
    924     no_done_at_end=config["no_done_at_end"],
    925     seed=(config["seed"] + worker_index)
    926     if config["seed"] is not None
    927     else None,
    928     fake_sampler=config["fake_sampler"],
    929     extra_python_environs=extra_python_environs,
    930     spaces=spaces,
    931     disable_env_checking=config["disable_env_checking"],
    932 )
    934 return worker

File ~\vlsecondrl\lib\site-packages\ray\rllib\evaluation\rollout_worker.py:604, in RolloutWorker.__init__(self, env_creator, validate_env, policy_spec, policy_mapping_fn, policies_to_train, tf_session_creator, rollout_fragment_length, count_steps_by, batch_mode, episode_horizon, preprocessor_pref, sample_async, compress_observations, num_envs, observation_fn, clip_rewards, normalize_actions, clip_actions, env_config, model_config, policy_config, worker_index, num_workers, recreated_worker, log_dir, log_level, callbacks, input_creator, output_creator, remote_worker_envs, remote_env_batch_wait_ms, soft_horizon, no_done_at_end, seed, extra_python_environs, fake_sampler, spaces, policy, disable_env_checking)
    602     devices = get_tf_gpu_devices()
    603 elif policy_config.get("framework") == "torch":
--> 604     devices = list(range(torch.cuda.device_count()))
    606 if len(devices) < num_gpus:
    607     raise RuntimeError(
    608         ERR_MSG_NO_GPUS.format(len(devices), devices) + HOWTO_CHANGE_CONFIG
    609     )

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cuda'

The error points to the line in RolloutWorker.init() where it attempts to call torch.cuda.device_count().
PyTorch Installation Check:
    import torch
    print(torch.__version__)  #output 2.3.0+cpu
    print(torch.cuda.is_available()) #output False

Weird thing is The same code runs perfectly in Google Colab (with no GPU enabled) but fails in my local environment in jupyter notebook.

"PyTorch (CPU version confirmed)" while your library is accessing torch.cuda. That's your problem! It seems you need a CUDA-compatible PyTorch version, not the CPU one.

@Ivan, I'm aiming to run the code entirely on CPU, similar to how it works in Colab without GPU. Why might Ray RLlib still attempt to access CUDA when I've configured it for no GPU use?

Well actually torch is None, how did you ray?

@Ivan, I initialized Ray using ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True) in my script after setting up the environment and ensuring PyTorch was installed correctly (PyTorch functions are recognized and torch.cuda.is_available() returns False).

sorry, I meant: "how did you install ray?"

I created a virtual environment with Python 3.9 and in it I installed ray with all the below libraries - '!pip install ray==2.1.0 ray[tune] ray[rllib] -U ray tensorflow==2.3.0 gym==0.13.1 or-gym'
